# How to query SELECT Then UPDATE in same function

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I got an error when I have second execute

```
All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 127.0.0.1:9042: 
ResponseError: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency 
QUORUM (2 required but only 1 alive). See innerErrors.
```

and i tried many thing to fixed this but nothing help

I have tried to change replication class from simplestartegy to networktopologystrategy also change replication factor to 3 but it doesn't work too.

this is my code
main.js :

```
const cqsql = require('./cqlfunction')
let insert_cassandra = async () => {
  try {
   let get_id = `SELECT next_id FROM ids WHERE id_name = 'person_id'`
   let last_id = await cqsql.cql_getofdb(get_id)
   let next_id = last_id[0].next_id
   let update_id = `UPDATE ids SET next_id = ${next_id + 1} WHERE id_name = 
   'person_id' IF next_id = ` + next_id
   let result = await cqsql.cql_execute(update_id)
   console.log(result);
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
   debugger
   process.exit()
  }
}
insert_cassandra()
```

cqlfunction.js :

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], localDataCenter: 'datacenter1', keyspace: 'javafrm'});

exports.cql_getofdb = async (query) => {
    try {
        // await client.connect()
        let result1 = await client.execute(query)
         if (result1.rowLength > 0) {
            return result1.rows
        } else {
            return []
        }
    } catch (error) {
        debugger
        console.error(error);
        return error
    }
}

exports.cql_execute = async (query) => {
    try {
        // await client.connect()
        debugger
        let result1 = await client.execute(query)
        return {}
    } catch (error) {
        debugger
        console.error(error);
        return error
    }
}
```

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27974911/not-enough-replica-available-for-query-at-consistency-one-1-required-but-only-0

Comment: I see you're connecting to 127.0.0.1.  Do you just have the one node?  If so, you'll want to keep RF=1 and not query at anything other than ONE as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the [replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeReplication.html), which is going to give resilience to your database, you may want to try different [consistency](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html) levels.

The select and update operations consider as an atomic operation is also known as a Compare and Set operation (CAS), which you can achieve with a [Lightweight transaction.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertLWT.html)